# Angular child component's view in parent component

Tags: html, css, angular

I've placed a table in my parent component's template and each line of this table is a child component that loop with *ngFor.

Parent template :

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th> 
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <app-liste-client-row *ngFor="let cli of clients" [client]="cli" >
    </app-liste-client-row>
</table>
```

template child :

```
<tr>
    <td>{{client.id}}</td>
    <td>{{client.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{client.lastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

The good point is I get to see all the lines of my table.

The bad point is I can't make the data lines match with the columns of my table. I tried using css (using ids with margin and padding) but it doesn't look like a proper solution since I had to play with the values. And I don't want to code my loop directly into my parent component either.

What is the easiest or more proper solution to have a clean table with a parent and child component ? Or am I missing something with the css ?

Comment: Table and it's child tags (td,th,tr) are not meant to have any other element (i.e. unknown dom element) in it. Inserting anything in between will break the DOM hierarchy of table element and hence you are getting a broken kind of table. See in the elements tab of your browser what dom it's generating...!! that might be helpful.

Comment: First, avoid plain inline styling, put your style in stylesheet or use Angular directives. Second, share with us your complete code, including styles, if you need help with your styles. Third, if you find it difficult to style your page, use some third-party solution such as Bootstrap or Angular Material.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use

```
<tr>
    <td>{{client.id}}</td>
    <td>{{client.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{client.lastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

as your child component. since tr is included in table. 
You should create a component for something if you are going to reuse it in many parts of you application. I'm assuming you will be using a whole table many times. so you should only have your parent component.

If you want to reuse your data, you should probably create a service that will provide your data.

but if you still want to do that you could try using [templates like in here](http://leon.radley.se/2016/05/multiple-trs-in-ng-for/).